# How to get values of only valid form fields in angular form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I am using the angular form, I want value of only valid fields in the form, here in picture mailing_zipcode field is invalid, so I
want to discard that value, is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: You can check if a control is valid using `this.formGroup.controls.myControl.valid`. This will return boolean value depending on its validity

Answer (score 0):

You could use a reactive form and check the validation status of every element, like I do check here the name validation status:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztjgg8?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/reactive/hero-form-reactive.component.ts

Afterwards you transfer your input data to da data object which you would sent do the server.